# Increase max-length for givenName attribute

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to create a user with the Graph API.
I experienced that the maximal length of a givenName can be 65 characters. 
When I'm trying with a longer value I get a Bad Request response with error CODE "InvalidLength".

I would like to have a limit of 100 characters for the name.

Is it possible to override the maximum length for the givenName attribute?

I'm calling the API with such a request:

```
HTTP POST graph.windows.net/***.onmicrosoft.com/users
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have confirmed with Azure support engineer, we can not override the maximum length for the givenName attribute. And 64 characters for the name should be enough.

If you must use an attribute with the length 100 characters or more. You can use extension attributes.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/using-extension-attributes-sample?view=azureadps-2.0